# Use htaccess to Modify shopping cart URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a shopping cart that has too many urls to each product. Each prod can have for example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/12345_this_is_seo_product
http://www.mysite.com/this_is_category/12345_this_is_seo_product
http://www.mysite.com/this_is_category/this_is_subcategory/12345_this_is_seo_product
```

I want to wind up with `http://www.mysite.com/12345_this_is_seo_product`
so I'm assuming the thing to do would be to kill everything between the `.com/` and the final `/`.

However, in the case of navigating categories you might have:

```
http://www.mysite.com/this_is_category/this_is_subcategory/
```

before you choose a product, which is desirable.

So that means that the stripping of everything between `.com` and the final `/` can only occur on products, and the only thing that sets products apart from other links is the fact that products start with a number, as in `12345_this_is_seo_product`

So what I need is a set of expressions that will strip everything between `.com` and the final `/` but only when immediately after the final `/` is a set of numbers (always four numbers or more)

Hopefully I made this clear without muddling it with too much explanation.

## edit - add my htaccess -

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -Indexes


<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">

 Order deny,allow

 Deny from all

</FilesMatch>


RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^.+/([0-9]+_[^/]+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]

RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)

RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this somewhere appropriate in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.+/([0-9]+-[^/]+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that didn't do anything to the product url. I'll include the code the exists is the htaccess now, as it takes the original product url and attempts to make it seo friendly. I placed your rewrite directly after this:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: @Bob You have to add it before any routing rules (anything rewriting to `index.php` or else the URI never reaches the redirect rule

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned I have tried it both before and after. The reason I assume it should go after is because the url is already rewritten from it's dynamic form. What I'm trying to do is then alter the result from that.

Sorry if the post above is garbled. The site kept telling me I had no characters left so I had to delete lines that would have made it easier to see what is going on in the htaccess file.

Comment: RewriteBase /

#nw-RewriteRule ^.+/([0-9]+_[^/]+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying to edit but I keep getting red-boxed saying I can only edit a reply for 5 minutes. 
Never been here before and trying to get in the groove of the way the site works I guess...

Comment: As it is originally, the htaccess file will render the following six urls for the same product. 


mp3-players/ipod_classic

mp3-players/ipod/ipod_classic

apple/ipod_classic

apple/ipod_classic?sort=pd.name&order=DESC&limit=50

ipod_classic?filter_name=classic

ipod_classic?filter_tag=ipod



This is not desireable for seo reasons. What I would like to do is wind up with h_tp://www.mysite.com/ipod_classic



second post to follow...

Comment: This is the part that does the rewriting

    RewriteBase /


    RewriteRule ^.+/([0-9]+_[^/]+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]


    RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]

    RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)

    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: @Bob I copy that and paste into a blank ht access file on a test apache setup and type in `http://localhost/this_is_category/12345_this_is_seo_product` in the browser and I got redirected to `http://localhost/12345_this_is_seo_product`. Note that the example you gave has *an underscore after the numeric ID* and that is what the rule matches against.

Comment: That's most likely the problem then - I gave your the wrong info!
It is a dash and not an underscore. They are all dashes, there are no underscores. Oops - sorry!

Comment: @Bob Then just replace the `_` with a `-` in the regular expression (edited my answer)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I've tried a few things and this seems to do the job:


    RewriteRule ^.+/([0-9]+[^-]+[^/]+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]


It rewrites the url like I wanted, except doing so has caused an unforseen problem where I have now lost my product images. As usual it's going to take more work than I had anticipated to get this done :(

Comment: I'm hitting the sack for tonight, it's 1 AM here. I really do appreciate all the help you gave. Thank you so much!!!